# Can pg_notify be as fast inside a trigger as outside?

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers, notifications, plpgsql

I noticed that statements like `SELECT pg_notify('foo', 'bar')` are incredibly quick to execute.

```
BenchmarkNotify-8                         257728             54542 ns/op
```

---

Then simple updates to random rows in a table are ~5x slower.

Init statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    int INT
);
```

Benchmarked statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (id, int) VALUES($1, $2)
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET int = $3
```

```
BenchmarkUpdate-8                          44913            289502 ns/op
```

---

But updates to a table with a trigger that runs `PERFORM pg_notify('foo', 'bar')` are ~5x slower still.

Init statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    int INT
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table1_fn() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    PERFORM pg_notify('foo', 'bar');
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER table1_trg AFTER UPDATE ON table1 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE table1_fn();
```

Benchmarked statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (id, int) VALUES($1, $2)
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET int = $3
```

```
BenchmarkUpdateTriggerNotify-8              8110           1502632 ns/op
```

---

I'd like to understand why this slowdown is so large and whether it can be avoided? I would expect `BenchmarkUpdateTriggerNotify` to be much closer to `BenchmarkUpdate` than it is.

#### Other Benchmarks I Tried

A benchmark on a table with a trigger that doesn't do anything was 4% slower than `BenchmarkUpdate`. A trigger that inserts to a different table was 12% slower than `BenchmarkUpdate`. Nothing like the 5x slowdown a call to `pg_notify` does. So I ruled out the simple presence of the trigger to be the cause.

I noticed that updating the same row every time without any triggers runs way closer to `BenchmarkUpdateNotifyTrigger` performance than `BenchmarkUpdate`. That made me think that maybe `pg_notify` prevents Postgres from parallelizing the workload in some way, but I'm only guessing here.

I also tried making the trigger a `CONSTRAINT` trigger and adding `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` parameters to it, to try to separate the transaction in which the update happens, and the notification is sent. It slowed `BenchmarkUpdateNotifyTrigger` further by ~22% instead of speeding it up.

#### How I Ran the Benchmarks

Put this code in a file `main_test.go` in an empty folder:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "sync"
    "testing"

    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4"
)

const (
    concurrency = 10
    tableSize   = 100
    connString  = "postgres://test:test@localhost:5432/test"
)

func sqlInit(ctx context.Context, sql string) error {
    conn, err := pgx.Connect(ctx, connString)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer conn.Close(ctx)

    _, err = conn.Exec(ctx, sql)
    return err
}

type sqlQuery struct {
    sql  string
    args []interface{}
}

type pool struct {
    sqlQueryCh chan sqlQuery
    wg         sync.WaitGroup

    err         error
    errMu       sync.Mutex
    nonNilErrCh chan struct{}
}

func newPool(ctx context.Context, cc int) (*pool, error) {
    ret := &pool{
        sqlQueryCh:  make(chan sqlQuery, cc),
        nonNilErrCh: make(chan struct{}),
    }

    for i := 0; i < cc; i++ {
        conn, err := pgx.Connect(ctx, connString)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        ret.wg.Add(1)
        go func(conn *pgx.Conn) {
            defer ret.wg.Done()
            defer conn.Close(ctx)

            for q := range ret.sqlQueryCh {
                if _, err := conn.Exec(ctx, q.sql, q.args...); err != nil {
                    ret.setErr(err)
                }
            }
        }(conn)
    }

    return ret, nil
}

func (p *pool) setErr(err error) {
    p.errMu.Lock()
    defer p.errMu.Unlock()
    if p.err == nil && err != nil {
        p.err = err
        close(p.nonNilErrCh)
    }
}

func (p *pool) Send(ctx context.Context, sql string, args ...interface{}) error {
    select {
    case p.sqlQueryCh <- sqlQuery{
        sql:  sql,
        args: args,
    }:
        return nil
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return ctx.Err()
    case <-p.nonNilErrCh:
        return p.err
    }
}

func (p *pool) Close() error {
    close(p.sqlQueryCh)
    p.wg.Wait()
    return p.err
}

func BenchmarkNotify(b *testing.B) {
    ctx := context.Background()

    if err := sqlInit(ctx, `
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    int INT
);`); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    pool, err := newPool(ctx, concurrency)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        if err := pool.Send(ctx, "SELECT pg_notify('foo', 'bar');"); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    if err := pool.Close(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func BenchmarkUpdate(b *testing.B) {
    ctx := context.Background()

    if err := sqlInit(ctx, `
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    int INT
);
`); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    pool, err := newPool(ctx, concurrency)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        if err := pool.Send(ctx, `
INSERT INTO table1 (id, int) VALUES($1, $2)
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET int = $3`, i%tableSize, 2, 3); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    if err := pool.Close(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func BenchmarkUpdateTriggerNotify(b *testing.B) {
    ctx := context.Background()

    if err := sqlInit(ctx, `
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    int INT
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table1_fn() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    PERFORM pg_notify('foo', 'bar');
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS table1_trg ON table1;
CREATE TRIGGER table1_trg AFTER UPDATE ON table1 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE table1_fn();
`); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    pool, err := newPool(ctx, concurrency)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        if err := pool.Send(ctx, `
INSERT INTO table1 (id, int) VALUES($1, $2)
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET int = $3`, i%tableSize, 2, 3); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    if err := pool.Close(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Run `go mod init test.com/m`

Run postgres docker image.

```bash
docker run -it -p 5433:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=test -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test -e POSTGRES_DB=test postgres
```

Run the benchmarks in another window.

```
go test . --bench=.
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: example.com/m
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
BenchmarkUpdate-8                       5182        309329 ns/op
BenchmarkUpdateTriggerNotify-8           895       1554109 ns/op
BenchmarkNotify-8                      27082         43838 ns/op
PASS
ok      example.com/m   7.840s
```

Comment: pg_notify does nothing - it just add some info to the one queue. Slow work is done at end of transaction, when data is taken from queue and distributed to  clients.

Comment: I think you will need to show the code.  I can't replicate either the high speed of the pg_notify or the low speed of the triggered update, using pgbench to drive them.

Comment: Thanks. Edited the question to include the code. I should (and will) try the same benchmarks with pgbench too.

Comment: @Circuitinthewall, were you able to identify the cause of the slowdown or find a workaround? I am experiencing similar effects with my use of NOTIFY triggers.